# Disable Autocomplete for User Input (within a Java Android App)

Tags: java, android, autocomplete, user-input

I want to **disable auto-correction and auto-complete** (word suggestions from the keyboard) on my cellphone
**within an app** I'm working on. 
It's a vocabulary trainer, so I want the User to type the input without using any tools.
Is there a way to do this with **Java**? Some relevant code snippets:

The user-interaction:

```
    public void onClick(View view) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textview);
        final String answer = textView.getText().toString();
        passData(answer);
    }
```

And the xml:

```
   <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button_first"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:background="#CCCCCC"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
```

P.S.
I'm new to App Development, so you might see some flaws in my code above - in that case, please tell me!

Answer (score 1):

Does it work if you add this to your `EditText`:

```
android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
```

Instead of:

```
android:inputType="textPersonName"
```

So it becomes this:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button_first"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:background="#CCCCCC"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Comment: Thanks, that tipped me off. For my case it doesn't work, but instead i can use:
android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"

Answer (score 1):

***Programatically***

```
sampleEdt.inputType = InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS
```

Documentation

> Can be combined with text and its variations to indicate that the IME should not show any dictionary-based word suggestions. Corresponds to InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS.